# JavaCL - Manage very large image processing

Tags: java, image-processing

I'm working on an industrial project dealing with large image processing (50Mo per image) and the key is performance.

I made the choice to delegate image processing to the GPU with the help of **JavaCL**. I write some tests in order to determine if the approach is correct. The results are clear !

Over 100 runs of image coloring GPU wins :
**GPU=172ms vs. CPU=438ms**

For now, it is clear that GPU is more powerful than CPU for this kind of computation BUT! there is a problem, a problem of memory. In fact, my graphic card has 256Mo of VRam and cannot allocate an image larger than 8Mo !

So, my question is, what is the best way for processing images larger than 8Mo ?

1. Tile the image and process each tile ? Will be performance killer
   due to the latency between RAM and VRAM
2. Extract raw pixels as float4 vectors and send them to the GPU ?
3. Change my graphic card ?
4. Throw the project ?
5. Drink more coffee ?

Thanks to all in advance :-)

Comment: I think you mean MB, for MegaBytes, instead of Mo.

Comment: Mo for mega-octets, the French for mega-bytes. Probably. Could be a typo too.

Comment: It's just because I'm french ... :-P So, ok MB (mega bytes)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not familiar with the JavaCL bindings - but in OpenCL, there are images and then there are buffers.

You can allocate buffers as large as possible, but there are limitations on the size of a cl_mem created using [clCreateImage2D](http://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/sdk/1.0/docs/man/xhtml/clCreateImage2D.html) (CL_DEVICE_IMAGE2D_MAX_WIDTH and CL_DEVICE_IMAGE2D_MAX_HEIGHT). An image has some advantages over a raw buffer, like providing hardware accelerated sampling. If you don't need sampling or can implement your own sampling inside the kernel - then it might be possible to use a buffer. Otherwise you will have to tile your input image and resolve any filtering artifacts that tile-processing will introduce.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks so much  !! I'll try to use buffers and see the performances.

Answer (score 1):

If you are open to the choice of the language then I would recommend you CUVI (http://cuvilib.com). It provides ready-made easy to use Imaging functionality. Lots of color operations, filters, edge detectors, arithmetic operations and what not. It's in C with a very neat C++ modular interface.

And yes, you can allocate large images too!

I can help you (or anyone else interested) in getting started with CUVI. The online wiki (http://wiki.cuvilib.com) is the right place to get started.

Disclosure: I'm part of the team that developed CUVI. Also, CUVI is a commercial software